# QTreeView StandardItem.insertRow(0, new_item) inserts itself instead of new_item?

Tags: python, qtreeview, qstandarditem, pyside6

I want to insert an new item to my treeview at row 0 of a child item.
The code seemed pretty straight forward but I think I have run into a bug?
I simplified the problem in order to avoid tons of unneeded code.
Is there something I am doing wrong?

To be clear, if I call insertRow() on the StandardItemModel itself... it does work.
Yet I need it to work on a sub item of the model.

QT version      : 6.0.0
PySide version  : 6.0.0
OS: Ubuntu 20.10 (KDE)

```
class MyTreeView(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        model = MyModel()
        self.setModel(model)
    
class MyModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root_item = self.invisibleRootItem()
        self.top_level = QStandardItem("Top level")
        self.root_item.appendRow(self.top_level)

        self.top_level.appendRow(QStandardItem('Appended item'))
        self.top_level.insertRow(0, QStandardItem('Inserted item'))
```

Now I would expect a result like:

```
    - Top level
      - Inserted item
      - Appended item
```

Yet the result I am getting is:

```
    - Top level
      - Top level
      - Appended item
```

Comment: It seems a bug, on PyQt5 it works fine. What if you just append the top level item to the model (using `self.appendRow(self.top_level)`), instead of trying to use the root item? It's also considered the normal usage, as the invisible root item is intended for recursive functions only.

Comment: @musicamante Mixed results, seem to work sometimes, sometimes not? Also I need to insert the row on a sub child of the root. means I need to call the insertRow() on the Item and not the Model.

Comment: I got that, you have to use `self.appendRow()` only for top level item(s), obviously. With the provided code, there's no reason for having different behaviors if you're correctly using `appendRow()` only for top level items (unless it's a bug, but it seems a bit strange, as it would be a *huge* bug).

Comment: @FlipVernooij change `self.top_level.insertRow(0, QStandardItem('Inserted item'))` to  `self.t = QStandardItem('Inserted item')`  `self.top_level.insertRow(0, self.t)`. Note: with your code I do not get the parent item as the one you indicate if not an empty item with PySide6 6.0.2

Comment: @eyllanesc mm you are right, when setting it as a persistent property it does work. Now I just figure out how to do that in the actual code. TNX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you insertRow() an item directly, it will go out of scope.
The solution for this example would be to assign it to self first.

I still assume this is a bug as appendRow() does mimic this behaviour.

```
class MyTreeView(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        model = MyModel()
        self.setModel(model)
    
class MyModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root_item = self.invisibleRootItem()
        self.top_level = QStandardItem("Top level")
        self.root_item.appendRow(self.top_level)

        self.top_level.appendRow(QStandardItem('Appended item'))
        # CHANGE START
        self.insert_item = QStandardItem('Inserted item')
        self.top_level.insertRow(0, self.insert_item)
        # CHANGE END
```